# broadcast message over bluetooth from android device

Tags: android, ios, bluetooth, broadcast

I want to broadcast simple short message from Android device to iOS and Android devices nearby. The message is short enough and static, so it can even be put as device bluetooth name as far as i concerned. The only requirement is that my app on other devices (iOS and Android) can read it without pairing.

Is that possible? If yes, how? I heard of bonjour, but is it possible to broadcast simple message between Android and iOS using it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know what the purpose would be, but if you think the message is short enough change the name of the adapter.

```
String message = "Read me before I change!";
BluetoothAdapter myAdapter = getDefaultAdapter();
myAdapter.setName(message);
```

Comment: thx! can i see that name using iOS device?
Purpose is to broadcast verification code to my iOS and Android app, and t needs to work crossplatform.

Comment: Yes, if both devices are bluetooth enabled and device1 scans for other devices it will see device2's name. And vice versa. Neither have to pair.